# NSMutableArray is thread safe?

Tags: iphone, thread-safety

Can anybody give me example that NSMutableArray is thread safe or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Thread-safe NSMutableArray question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703294/thread-safe-nsmutablearray-question)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Synchronizing NSMutableArray for Thread Security](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521190/synchronizing-nsmutablearray-for-thread-security)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not thread safe. See the list of thread safe/unsafe classes [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html)

Answer (score 6):

According to the Apple docs NSMutableArray is not thread safe.

> Mutable objects are generally not
>   thread-safe. To use mutable objects in
>   a threaded application, the
>   application must synchronize access to
>   them using locks. (For more
>   information, see “Atomic Operations”).
>   In general, the collection classes
>   (for example, NSMutableArray,
>   NSMutableDictionary) are not
>   thread-safe when mutations are
>   concerned. That is, if one or more
>   threads are changing the same array,
>   problems can occur. You must lock
>   around spots where reads and writes
>   occur to assure thread safety.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html